# Button is not available

Tags: android, android-button

I am new to Android and I have a command like this

```
Button btn1  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEnter); 
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View V){            
        dialog.dismiss();
        setContentView(R.layout.tflist);
        Button btnTF=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BTNTfDef);
        Button btnTFK=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BTNTfComm);
        Button btnTFS=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BTNTfOffice);
        Button btnReturn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BTNReturnTF);
        btnTF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            setContentView(R.layout.tarafhesab);
            Button btnTfSabt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SetTf);
            Button btnTfRefresh=(Button)findViewById(R.id.RefreshTf);
            Button btnTfReturn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Returnlist);
            btnTfSabt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View V){ 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ثبت طرف حساب ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        btnTfRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View V){ 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "جستجوی طرف حساب بر اساس اطلاعات وارد شده  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        btnTfReturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View V){ 
                dialog.dismiss();
                setContentView(R.layout.tflist);
            }
        });
```

My form opens, but my Buttons have no action.
What is the problem?

Comment: can you tell what is this `setContentView(R.layout.tablelayout);`

Comment: @shirin abbasi what are trying to do here

Comment: try to create a new button object Button cancel = new Button...cancel.setOnClickListener....

Comment: @MaharithAdityaSS she is trying to set an onClickListener on the button

Comment: @bub I can see that i asked about setcontentView inside that

Comment: ,when I click on calnclebtn,this command opens my new form(tablelayout),but buttons are not active... I used the startActivity command ,but my system is stopped

Comment: Are you trying to start a new activity with this? Is table layout.xml a new activity?

Comment: please show us a little bit more of your code....I guess this is done in the wrong place....

Comment: @shirinabbasi Post more *code* to get the exact issue.

Comment: Thanks all, I edit my question and I put my code about one of the buttons

Comment: Why are you calling _setContentView_ at every place? What do you want exactly ?

Comment: every button open new form

Comment: Then u can call new activity or open pop up window

Comment: I used from new activity,but my app is stopped

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind button before adding the onclick listener

```
Canclebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id_in_layout);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have it,but it doesn't work yet